# Angular4+ No value accessor for form control

Tags: angular, contenteditable, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having big troubles with angular form value accessor.
The error is the following : "No value accessor for form control with name: 'textTitle'" from SectionComponent.ngfactory.js
I'm using an angular lib called ContentEditable that implements ControlValueAccessor to set text to editable and link it to a form.

Here is my reactive form :

```
  this.form = new FormGroup({
  descriptionText : new FormControl(this.descriptionText),
  textTitle: new FormControl(this.titleText),
  buttonText : new FormControl(this.buttonText)
  })
```

Here is one of the editable content :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<div class="descriptionSectionBlock title" [ngStyle]='{  }'
     *ngIf="currentSection.titleText.textDisplayed" >
  <div [ngStyle]='{ }'>
    <h2 contentEditable="true" formControlName="textTitle"
        (blur)="updateTextContent('title')"
        [ngStyle]='{ }'>
      {{titleText}}
    </h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="descriptionSectionBlock description" [ngStyle]='{  }'
     *ngIf="currentSection.descriptionText.textDisplayed" >
  <div [ngStyle]='{  }'>
    <p contentEditable="true" formControlName="descriptionText"
       (blur)="updateTextContent('description')"
       [ngStyle]='{  }'>
      {{descriptionText}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div [ngStyle]='{ }' class="descriptionSectionBlock button"
     *ngIf="currentSection.CTAButtonDisplay">
  <button contentEditable="true" formControlName="buttonText" (mouseover)="hover=true" (mouseleave)="hover=false"
          (blur)="updateTextContent('button')"
          [ngStyle]='{
           }' mat-raised-button>
    {{buttonText}}
  </button>
</div>
</form>
```

I don't understand what i did wrong. Thanks for helping.

Comment: what's a problem/exception?

Comment: I got a "No value accessor for form control with name: 'textTitle'" coming from SectionComponent.ngfactory.js :/
Same for descriptionTitle and buttonTitle...

Comment: did you import the module?

Comment: Yeah, both form and reactiveform are imported :/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was because i used the contentEditable property and not the contenteditable one...

I love this kind of error description...

Answer (score 0):

formControlName must be used on **input** html tags

Comment: No it should be usable on every component that implements the FormValueAccessor

Comment: **formControlName** is intended to be for input purpose, and if you want output you should do {{form.get('description').value}}.

Can you at least give a try?

Comment: The whole purpose of the contentEditable lib is to allow text to be edited. They even wrote on their github that FormValueAccesor has been implemented. I can't and I won't use input since it would not be the behavior I'm looking for...

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your comment I think ^^ you were taking about input property?

Comment: Understand. I hope you'll find the solution because from what I feel you won't be able to do that with ReactiveForms. Maybe to try to use the ngModel?

Comment: I'm talking about **p** html element to be converted to **input** html element

Comment: I'll try to replace with input tomorrow just to see if that's really the problem. Thanks for your help.